# embed not working in IE

Tags: html

I am trying to embed my A sites to B Site it's working fine in Firefox.. but having problem in IE(7 & 8)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <object data=http://time.mysite.pvt width="800" height="800"> <embed src=http://time.mysite.pvt width="800" height="800"></embed>
     Error: Embedded Data could not be displayed.

</object>
</head>
</html>
```

Please help me on this

Comment: what is pvt? If you want to embed html content use `iframe` element instead.

Comment: This is nothing to do with embedded computing - see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info. Retagged.

Comment: Fixing the [obvious errors](http://validator.w3.org/) would be a logical starting point.

Comment: hi can you please write a iframe code for me..

Comment: @Brahm Dutt, glad you found an answer that helped. You can accept it by clicking the check mark beside the answer and under the vote ticker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use iframe?

```
<iframe src="http://time.mysite.pvt" width="800" height="800"></iframe>
```

> http://www.iframehtml.com/